# How to split a sentence into words by detecting space in clojure

Tags: clojure

I want to split a sentence into words by detecting space. For instance,

```
user=>(split "I like reading books")
["I" "like" "reading" "books"]
```

My code is

```
(use '[clojure.string :only(split triml)])
```

but when I compile it, I got "nil"

```
(load-file "file")
nil  
user=>(split "I like reading books")
["I" "like" "reading" "books"]
```

How can I do to get rid of "nil" or is there any other ways to divide the sentences into words without slide-effect. Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand your question; `(clojure.string/split "I like reading books" #"\s+")` works just fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

I kind of got the point you stuck, so I'll try to answer it.

Apparently, you're running an REPL session. REPL, WILL, accept input expression, evaluate it, and output the evaluated result.

When you input `(load-file "file")`, it's an expression, not an instruction, and it will have a return value, i.e., `nil`. We are evaluating this expression simply for its side effect --- to load the corresponding file. Note the difference: `nil` is the result, loading the code is side effect.

You can't, not in my knowledge, suppress the return value from REPL. But you really should not worry about that. You're not going to run REPL in production, are you?

Answer (score 1):

To split a sentence into words by detecting space, you must call

```
(clojure.string/split your-sentence #" ")
```

or in your case

```
(clojure.string/split "I like reading books" #" ")
```

'split' requires two parameters: The first is the string you want to split, and the second is the regular expression on which the string must be split.

See here for more details:

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/split